# Javascript change event never called

Tags: javascript

I have this order question related top javascript. In the aspx page I have this `SubmissionMaintenance.init` that call this return classes in javascript `getRecord` and `saveRecord`. I wanted to add a `$("#ddlCompany").change` event and no matter when I add it it will never get called.

aspx Page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SubmissionMaintenance.init();
    });
```

JS Page

```
return {
    init: function () {
        getRecord();
        
        saveRecord();
    }
}


var getRecord = function () {

    html += "<select class='form-control select2-multiple' multiple='multiple' id='ddlCompany' name='ddlCompany' >";
    
    $("#submission").html(html);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add the change event listener to a parent element because the element you want to listen to is added after the dom has loaded.

Try this:

```
$( "#submission" ).on( "change", "#ddlCompany", function() {
  console.log( '#ddlCompany change' );
});
```